# Animate node color in same figure using updated data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, networkx, matplotlib-animation

I created a network graph using node and edge files. Node files changed every 10 seconds using another code and the edge file is static.
For plotting using updated I band client socket code with ploting code.

But the problem is whenever Server send updated file to client, then new plotting figure show. Thats why on my screen N number of plotted figure shows.
And I want to animated only node color according to node status in same figre like this.
[What tool to draw an animated network graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376066/what-tool-to-draw-an-animated-network-graph)

Client side code -

```
if len(text2) < 30:
            if CL[0] == "get":
                for i in range(20):
                    BigC = open("Received-" + CL[1], "wb")
                    d = 0
                    try:
                            # number of paclets
                        CountC, countaddress = s.recvfrom(4096)
                    except ConnectionResetError:
                        print(
                            "Error. Port numbers not matching.")
                        sys.exit()
                    except:
                        print("Timeout or some other error")
                        sys.exit()

                    tillC = CountC.decode('utf8')
                    tillCC = int(tillC)
                    #print("Receiving packets will start now if file exists.")
                    # print(
                    #   "Timeout is 15 seconds so please wait for timeout at the end.")
                    while tillCC != 0:
                        ClientBData, clientbAddr = s.recvfrom(4096)
                        dataS = BigC.write(ClientBData)
                        d += 1
                        print("Received packet number:" + str(d))
                        tillCC = tillCC - 1

                    #BigC.close()
                    print(
                        "Check contents in your directory.")
                    os.system('python3 plotting.py &')
                time.sleep(3)
```

Plotting code -

```
fig = plt.figure()
net = fig.add_subplot(111)

def init_func():
    with open("fileName", 'r') as nodecsv:
        nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv)
        nodes = [n for n in nodereader][1:]
        node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes]

    with open("fileName", 'r') as edgecsv:
        edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv)
        edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader][1:]

    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from(node_names)
    g.add_edges_from(edges)
    
    node_status = {}
    for node in nodes:
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            node_status[node[0]] = node[1]
        else:
            node_status[node[0]] = 'R'
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, node_status, 'node_status')
********** other coding***********

    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_title('Graph')
    global pos
    pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(g)
    nx.draw(g, pos=pos, node_size=node_size, node_color=color_map, linewidths=2, **options)

def update(it):
***************Same as above**************
    nx.draw(g, pos=pos, node_size=node_size, node_color=color_map, linewidths=2, **options)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init_func ,interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Which one is the server? A *client-server* interaction works like this: the server opens a socket and passively listens; the client opens a socket to connect to the server, the server accepts the connection and reacts to the client request. I don't recognize this dynamic in your code.